# Is it possible to start / stop a node via libcloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, libcloud

I'm trying to find a way to stop or start a node (device, instance) via libcloud and I cannot find a method for this.
Could this basic functionality be missing?
I'm now looking for working against EC2, but may need to work against other providers as well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To stop a running node given that instance ID is known for a given region.

```
cls = get_driver(Provider.EC2_AP_NORTHEAST)
driver = cls(access_key, secret_key)
nodes = driver.list_nodes()
node_id = "i-xyz"        
inst = [i for i in nodes if i.id == node_id][0]
driver.ex_stop_node(inst)
```

To start a stopped node.

```
cls = get_driver(Provider.EC2_AP_NORTHEAST)
driver = cls(access_key, secret_key)
nodes = driver.list_nodes()
node_id = "i-xyz"        
inst = [i for i in nodes if i.id == node_id][0]
driver.ex_start_node(inst)
```